# How to: install mps-youtube without installing a desktop

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation

I have just installed Ubuntu server 20.04 on a headless Raspberry pi 3B+.

I would like to install mps-youtube but for some reason it wants me to install Gnome desktop.

How can I install mps-youtube without installing any gui related package?

```
sudo apt install mps-youtube
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  acl adwaita-icon-theme apg aptdaemon aptdaemon-data aspell aspell-en at-spi2-core
  avahi-daemon avahi-utils bluez bubblewrap cheese-common colord colord-data
  cracklib-runtime cups-pk-helper dbus-x11 dconf-cli desktop-file-utils dictionaries-common
  docbook-xml emacsen-common enchant-2 evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-common
  ffmpeg fontconfig fprintd gcr gdm3 geoclue-2.0 gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0 gir1.2-atk-1.0
  gir1.2-atspi-2.0 gir1.2-freedesktop gir1.2-gck-1 gir1.2-gcr-3 gir1.2-gdesktopenums-3.0
  gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-gdm-1.0 gir1.2-geoclue-2.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0
  gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 gir1.2-graphene-1.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-gweather-3.0
  gir1.2-ibus-1.0 gir1.2-json-1.0 gir1.2-mutter-6 gir1.2-nm-1.0 gir1.2-nma-1.0
  gir1.2-notify-0.7 gir1.2-pango-1.0 gir1.2-polkit-1.0 gir1.2-rsvg-2.0 gir1.2-secret-1
  gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0 gir1.2-vte-2.91 gjs gkbd-capplet
  gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data gnome-control-center-faces
  gnome-desktop3-data gnome-keyring gnome-keyring-pkcs11 gnome-menus gnome-online-accounts
  gnome-session-bin gnome-session-common gnome-settings-daemon gnome-settings-daemon-common
  gnome-shell gnome-shell-common gnome-startup-applications gnome-user-docs
  gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0 gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
  gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio gstreamer1.0-x gtk-update-icon-cache hicolor-icon-theme
  humanity-icon-theme hunspell-en-us ibus ibus-data ibus-gtk ibus-gtk3 iio-sensor-proxy
  im-config ippusbxd language-selector-gnome libaa1 libaacs0 libaom0 libappindicator3-1
  libaspell15 libass9 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libatspi2.0-0
  libauthen-sasl-perl libavahi-core7 libavahi-glib1 libavc1394-0 libavcodec58 libavdevice58
  libavfilter7 libavformat58 libavresample4 libavutil56 libbdplus0 libbluetooth3 libbluray2
  libbs2b0 libcaca0 libcairo-gobject2 libcamel-1.2-62 libcanberra-gtk3-0
  libcanberra-gtk3-module libcanberra-pulse libcdio-cdda2 libcdio-paranoia2 libcdio18
  libcheese-gtk25 libcheese8 libchromaprint1 libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-1.0-common
  libclutter-gst-3.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcodec2-0.9 libcogl-common libcogl-pango20
  libcogl-path20 libcogl20 libcolord-gtk1 libcolord2 libcolorhug2 libcrack2 libdaemon0
  libdata-dump-perl libdatrie1 libdbus-glib-1-2 libdbusmenu-glib4 libdbusmenu-gtk3-4
  libdc1394-22 libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1 libdv4 libdvdnav4 libdvdread7
  libebackend-1.2-10 libebook-1.2-20 libebook-contacts-1.2-3 libecal-2.0-1
  libedata-book-1.2-26 libedata-cal-2.0-1 libedataserver-1.2-24 libedataserverui-1.2-2
  libegl-mesa0 libegl1 libenchant-2-2 libencode-locale-perl libepoxy0 libevdev2 libexif12
  libfftw3-double3 libfile-basedir-perl libfile-desktopentry-perl libfile-listing-perl
  libfile-mimeinfo-perl libflite1 libfont-afm-perl libfontenc1 libfprint-2-2
  libfprint-2-tod1 libgail-common libgail18 libgbm1 libgck-1-0 libgcr-base-3-1
  libgcr-ui-3-1 libgd3 libgdata-common libgdata22 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgdm1 libgee-0.8-2 libgeoclue-2-0 libgeocode-glib0 libgjs0g
  libgl1 libgl1-mesa-dri libglapi-mesa libgles2 libglvnd0 libglx-mesa0 libglx0 libgme0
  libgnome-autoar-0-0 libgnome-bluetooth13 libgnome-desktop-3-19 libgnomekbd-common
  libgnomekbd8 libgoa-1.0-0b libgoa-1.0-common libgoa-backend-1.0-1 libgphoto2-6
  libgphoto2-l10n libgphoto2-port12 libgraphene-1.0-0 libgraphite2-3 libgsm1 libgsound0
  libgssdp-1.2-0 libgstreamer-gl1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0 libgtk-3-0
  libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin libgtk2.0-common libgtop-2.0-11
  libgtop2-common libgupnp-1.2-0 libgupnp-av-1.0-2 libgupnp-dlna-2.0-3 libgweather-3-16
  libgweather-common libharfbuzz-icu0 libharfbuzz0b libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl
  libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-tree-perl libhttp-cookies-perl
  libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl libhttp-negotiate-perl
  libhunspell-1.7-0 libhyphen0 libibus-1.0-5 libical3 libiec61883-0 libieee1284-3
  libimobiledevice6 libinput-bin libinput10 libio-html-perl libio-socket-ssl-perl
  libio-stringy-perl libipc-system-simple-perl libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libjbig0
  libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 liblcms2-2 liblilv-0-0 libllvm10 liblua5.2-0
  liblwp-mediatypes-perl liblwp-protocol-https-perl libmailtools-perl libmbim-glib4
  libmbim-proxy libmediaart-2.0-0 libmm-glib0 libmozjs-68-0 libmp3lame0 libmpg123-0
  libmtdev1 libmutter-6-0 libmysofa1 libmysqlclient21 libndp0 libnet-dbus-perl
  libnet-http-perl libnet-smtp-ssl-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libnm0 libnma0 libnorm1
  libnotify4 libnspr4 libnss-mdns libnss3 libopenal-data libopenal1 libopenjp2-7
  libopenmpt0 libpam-fprintd libpam-gnome-keyring libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0
  libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpangoxft-1.0-0 libpciaccess0 libpgm-5.2-0 libphonenumber7 libplist3
  libpostproc55 libprotobuf17 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpwquality-common libpwquality1
  libqmi-glib5 libqmi-proxy libraw1394-11 librest-0.7-0 librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common
  librubberband2 librygel-core-2.6-2 librygel-db-2.6-2 librygel-renderer-2.6-2
  librygel-server-2.6-2 libsane libsane-common libsbc1 libsdl2-2.0-0 libsecret-1-0
  libsecret-common libsensors-config libsensors5 libserd-0-0 libshine3 libshout3
  libsmbclient libsnappy1v5 libsndio7.0 libsnmp-base libsnmp35 libsord-0-0
  libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libspeex1 libsratom-0-0 libssh-gcrypt-4 libstartup-notification0
  libswresample3 libswscale5 libtag1v5 libtag1v5-vanilla libteamdctl0 libthai-data libthai0
  libtie-ixhash-perl libtiff5 libtimedate-perl libtry-tiny-perl libtwolame0 libudisks2-0
  libunwind8 libupower-glib3 liburi-perl libusbmuxd6 libv4l-0 libv4lconvert0 libva-drm2
  libva-wayland2 libva-x11-2 libva2 libvdpau1 libvidstab1.1 libvpx6 libvte-2.91-0
  libvte-2.91-common libvulkan1 libwacom-bin libwacom-common libwacom2 libwavpack1
  libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0 libwayland-egl1 libwayland-server0
  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libwebp6 libwebpdemux2 libwebpmux3 libwhoopsie-preferences0
  libwhoopsie0 libwoff1 libwww-perl libwww-robotrules-perl libx11-protocol-perl libx264-155
  libx265-179 libxaw7 libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-icccm4 libxcb-image0
  libxcb-keysyms1 libxcb-present0 libxcb-randr0 libxcb-render-util0 libxcb-res0
  libxcb-shape0 libxcb-sync1 libxcb-util1 libxcb-xfixes0 libxcb-xkb1 libxcb-xv0
  libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxfixes3 libxfont2 libxft2 libxi6 libxinerama1
  libxkbcommon-x11-0 libxkbcommon0 libxkbfile1 libxklavier16 libxml-parser-perl
  libxml-twig-perl libxml-xpathengine-perl libxmu6 libxpm4 libxrandr2 libxshmfence1
  libxslt1.1 libxss1 libxt6 libxv1 libxvidcore4 libxxf86dga1 libxxf86vm1 libyelp0 libzmq5
  libzvbi-common libzvbi0 mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers
  mobile-broadband-provider-info modemmanager mousetweaks mpv mutter mutter-common
  mysql-common network-manager network-manager-gnome network-manager-pptp
  ocl-icd-libopencl1 p11-kit p11-kit-modules perl-openssl-defaults pinentry-gnome3 ppp
  pptp-linux pulseaudio-module-bluetooth python3-aptdaemon python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets
  python3-cairo python3-cups python3-cupshelpers python3-defer python3-ibus-1.0
  python3-macaroonbakery python3-pafy python3-protobuf python3-pyxattr python3-rfc3339
  python3-tz rtmpdump rygel sane-utils session-migration sgml-base sgml-data
  switcheroo-control system-config-printer system-config-printer-common
  system-config-printer-udev ubuntu-docs ubuntu-mono ubuntu-session ubuntu-wallpapers
  ubuntu-wallpapers-focal unzip update-inetd upower usb-modeswitch usb-modeswitch-data
  usbmuxd va-driver-all vdpau-driver-all wamerican whoopsie-preferences x11-utils
  x11-xkb-utils x11-xserver-utils xclip xdg-dbus-proxy xdg-utils xfonts-base
  xfonts-encodings xfonts-utils xml-core xserver-common xserver-xephyr xserver-xorg
  xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-input-libinput
  xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-legacy xserver-xorg-video-all
  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-fbdev
  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-vesa xwayland
  yaru-theme-gnome-shell yelp yelp-xsl youtube-dl zenity zenity-common
Suggested packages:
  aspell-doc spellutils avahi-autoipd colord-sensor-argyll docbook docbook-dsssl
  docbook-xsl docbook-defguide evolution ffmpeg-doc gnome-orca gnome-software
  | gnome-packagekit gnome-user-share realmd libcanberra-gtk-module usbguard
  chrome-gnome-shell gir1.2-telepathyglib-0.12 gnome-themes-standard-data gnome-backgrounds
  gir1.2-telepathylogger-0.2 hunspell openoffice.org-hunspell | openoffice.org-core
  ibus-clutter ibus-doc indicator-application libdigest-hmac-perl libgssapi-perl
  libbluray-bdj libdv-bin oss-compat libdvdcss2 libenchant-2-voikko libfftw3-bin
  libfftw3-dev libgd-tools gphoto2 gvfs libusbmuxd-tools liblcms2-utils
  libcrypt-ssleay-perl avahi-autoipd | zeroconf libportaudio2 libraw1394-doc librsvg2-bin
  hplip lm-sensors serdi sndiod snmp-mibs-downloader sordi speex gstreamer1.0-libav
  libauthen-ntlm-perl libunicode-map8-perl libunicode-string-perl xml-twig-tools
  libteam-utils network-manager-openconnect-gnome network-manager-openvpn-gnome
  network-manager-vpnc-gnome network-manager-pptp-gnome opencl-icd pinentry-doc
  python3-pyxattr-dbg python-pyxattr-doc gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly rygel-playbin
  rygel-preferences rygel-ruih rygel-tracker tumbler unpaper sgml-base-doc perlsgml w3-recs
  opensp libxml2-utils gnome-software python3-smbc ubuntu-wallpapers-karmic
  ubuntu-wallpapers-lucid ubuntu-wallpapers-maverick ubuntu-wallpapers-natty
  ubuntu-wallpapers-oneiric ubuntu-wallpapers-precise ubuntu-wallpapers-quantal
  ubuntu-wallpapers-raring ubuntu-wallpapers-saucy ubuntu-wallpapers-trusty
  ubuntu-wallpapers-utopic ubuntu-wallpapers-vivid ubuntu-wallpapers-wily
  ubuntu-wallpapers-xenial ubuntu-wallpapers-yakkety ubuntu-wallpapers-zesty
  ubuntu-wallpapers-artful ubuntu-wallpapers-bionic ubuntu-wallpapers-cosmic
  ubuntu-wallpapers-disco ubuntu-wallpapers-eoan zip comgt wvdial libvdpau-va-gl1
  mesa-utils nickle cairo-5c xorg-docs-core debhelper xfonts-100dpi | xfonts-75dpi
  xfonts-scalable xinput firmware-amd-graphics xserver-xorg-video-r128
  xserver-xorg-video-mach64 firmware-misc-nonfree libfribidi-bin | bidiv phantomjs
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  acl adwaita-icon-theme apg aptdaemon aptdaemon-data aspell aspell-en at-spi2-core
  avahi-daemon avahi-utils bluez bubblewrap cheese-common colord colord-data
  cracklib-runtime cups-pk-helper dbus-x11 dconf-cli desktop-file-utils dictionaries-common
  docbook-xml emacsen-common enchant-2 evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-common
  ffmpeg fontconfig fprintd gcr gdm3 geoclue-2.0 gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0 gir1.2-atk-1.0
  gir1.2-atspi-2.0 gir1.2-freedesktop gir1.2-gck-1 gir1.2-gcr-3 gir1.2-gdesktopenums-3.0
  gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-gdm-1.0 gir1.2-geoclue-2.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0
  gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 gir1.2-graphene-1.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-gweather-3.0
  gir1.2-ibus-1.0 gir1.2-json-1.0 gir1.2-mutter-6 gir1.2-nm-1.0 gir1.2-nma-1.0
  gir1.2-notify-0.7 gir1.2-pango-1.0 gir1.2-polkit-1.0 gir1.2-rsvg-2.0 gir1.2-secret-1
  gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0 gir1.2-vte-2.91 gjs gkbd-capplet
  gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data gnome-control-center-faces
  gnome-desktop3-data gnome-keyring gnome-keyring-pkcs11 gnome-menus gnome-online-accounts
  gnome-session-bin gnome-session-common gnome-settings-daemon gnome-settings-daemon-common
  gnome-shell gnome-shell-common gnome-startup-applications gnome-user-docs
  gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0 gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
  gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio gstreamer1.0-x gtk-update-icon-cache hicolor-icon-theme
  humanity-icon-theme hunspell-en-us ibus ibus-data ibus-gtk ibus-gtk3 iio-sensor-proxy
  im-config ippusbxd language-selector-gnome libaa1 libaacs0 libaom0 libappindicator3-1
  libaspell15 libass9 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libatspi2.0-0
  libauthen-sasl-perl libavahi-core7 libavahi-glib1 libavc1394-0 libavcodec58 libavdevice58
  libavfilter7 libavformat58 libavresample4 libavutil56 libbdplus0 libbluetooth3 libbluray2
  libbs2b0 libcaca0 libcairo-gobject2 libcamel-1.2-62 libcanberra-gtk3-0
  libcanberra-gtk3-module libcanberra-pulse libcdio-cdda2 libcdio-paranoia2 libcdio18
  libcheese-gtk25 libcheese8 libchromaprint1 libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-1.0-common
  libclutter-gst-3.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcodec2-0.9 libcogl-common libcogl-pango20
  libcogl-path20 libcogl20 libcolord-gtk1 libcolord2 libcolorhug2 libcrack2 libdaemon0
  libdata-dump-perl libdatrie1 libdbus-glib-1-2 libdbusmenu-glib4 libdbusmenu-gtk3-4
  libdc1394-22 libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1 libdv4 libdvdnav4 libdvdread7
  libebackend-1.2-10 libebook-1.2-20 libebook-contacts-1.2-3 libecal-2.0-1
  libedata-book-1.2-26 libedata-cal-2.0-1 libedataserver-1.2-24 libedataserverui-1.2-2
  libegl-mesa0 libegl1 libenchant-2-2 libencode-locale-perl libepoxy0 libevdev2 libexif12
  libfftw3-double3 libfile-basedir-perl libfile-desktopentry-perl libfile-listing-perl
  libfile-mimeinfo-perl libflite1 libfont-afm-perl libfontenc1 libfprint-2-2
  libfprint-2-tod1 libgail-common libgail18 libgbm1 libgck-1-0 libgcr-base-3-1
  libgcr-ui-3-1 libgd3 libgdata-common libgdata22 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgdm1 libgee-0.8-2 libgeoclue-2-0 libgeocode-glib0 libgjs0g
  libgl1 libgl1-mesa-dri libglapi-mesa libgles2 libglvnd0 libglx-mesa0 libglx0 libgme0
  libgnome-autoar-0-0 libgnome-bluetooth13 libgnome-desktop-3-19 libgnomekbd-common
  libgnomekbd8 libgoa-1.0-0b libgoa-1.0-common libgoa-backend-1.0-1 libgphoto2-6
  libgphoto2-l10n libgphoto2-port12 libgraphene-1.0-0 libgraphite2-3 libgsm1 libgsound0
  libgssdp-1.2-0 libgstreamer-gl1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0 libgtk-3-0
  libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin libgtk2.0-common libgtop-2.0-11
  libgtop2-common libgupnp-1.2-0 libgupnp-av-1.0-2 libgupnp-dlna-2.0-3 libgweather-3-16
  libgweather-common libharfbuzz-icu0 libharfbuzz0b libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl
  libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-tree-perl libhttp-cookies-perl
  libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl libhttp-negotiate-perl
  libhunspell-1.7-0 libhyphen0 libibus-1.0-5 libical3 libiec61883-0 libieee1284-3
  libimobiledevice6 libinput-bin libinput10 libio-html-perl libio-socket-ssl-perl
  libio-stringy-perl libipc-system-simple-perl libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libjbig0
  libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 liblcms2-2 liblilv-0-0 libllvm10 liblua5.2-0
  liblwp-mediatypes-perl liblwp-protocol-https-perl libmailtools-perl libmbim-glib4
  libmbim-proxy libmediaart-2.0-0 libmm-glib0 libmozjs-68-0 libmp3lame0 libmpg123-0
  libmtdev1 libmutter-6-0 libmysofa1 libmysqlclient21 libndp0 libnet-dbus-perl
  libnet-http-perl libnet-smtp-ssl-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libnm0 libnma0 libnorm1
  libnotify4 libnspr4 libnss-mdns libnss3 libopenal-data libopenal1 libopenjp2-7
  libopenmpt0 libpam-fprintd libpam-gnome-keyring libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0
  libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpangoxft-1.0-0 libpciaccess0 libpgm-5.2-0 libphonenumber7 libplist3
  libpostproc55 libprotobuf17 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpwquality-common libpwquality1
  libqmi-glib5 libqmi-proxy libraw1394-11 librest-0.7-0 librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common
  librubberband2 librygel-core-2.6-2 librygel-db-2.6-2 librygel-renderer-2.6-2
  librygel-server-2.6-2 libsane libsane-common libsbc1 libsdl2-2.0-0 libsecret-1-0
  libsecret-common libsensors-config libsensors5 libserd-0-0 libshine3 libshout3
  libsmbclient libsnappy1v5 libsndio7.0 libsnmp-base libsnmp35 libsord-0-0
  libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libspeex1 libsratom-0-0 libssh-gcrypt-4 libstartup-notification0
  libswresample3 libswscale5 libtag1v5 libtag1v5-vanilla libteamdctl0 libthai-data libthai0
  libtie-ixhash-perl libtiff5 libtimedate-perl libtry-tiny-perl libtwolame0 libudisks2-0
  libunwind8 libupower-glib3 liburi-perl libusbmuxd6 libv4l-0 libv4lconvert0 libva-drm2
  libva-wayland2 libva-x11-2 libva2 libvdpau1 libvidstab1.1 libvpx6 libvte-2.91-0
  libvte-2.91-common libvulkan1 libwacom-bin libwacom-common libwacom2 libwavpack1
  libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0 libwayland-egl1 libwayland-server0
  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libwebp6 libwebpdemux2 libwebpmux3 libwhoopsie-preferences0
  libwhoopsie0 libwoff1 libwww-perl libwww-robotrules-perl libx11-protocol-perl libx264-155
  libx265-179 libxaw7 libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-icccm4 libxcb-image0
  libxcb-keysyms1 libxcb-present0 libxcb-randr0 libxcb-render-util0 libxcb-res0
  libxcb-shape0 libxcb-sync1 libxcb-util1 libxcb-xfixes0 libxcb-xkb1 libxcb-xv0
  libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxfixes3 libxfont2 libxft2 libxi6 libxinerama1
  libxkbcommon-x11-0 libxkbcommon0 libxkbfile1 libxklavier16 libxml-parser-perl
  libxml-twig-perl libxml-xpathengine-perl libxmu6 libxpm4 libxrandr2 libxshmfence1
  libxslt1.1 libxss1 libxt6 libxv1 libxvidcore4 libxxf86dga1 libxxf86vm1 libyelp0 libzmq5
  libzvbi-common libzvbi0 mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers
  mobile-broadband-provider-info modemmanager mousetweaks mps-youtube mpv mutter
  mutter-common mysql-common network-manager network-manager-gnome network-manager-pptp
  ocl-icd-libopencl1 p11-kit p11-kit-modules perl-openssl-defaults pinentry-gnome3 ppp
  pptp-linux pulseaudio-module-bluetooth python3-aptdaemon python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets
  python3-cairo python3-cups python3-cupshelpers python3-defer python3-ibus-1.0
  python3-macaroonbakery python3-pafy python3-protobuf python3-pyxattr python3-rfc3339
  python3-tz rtmpdump rygel sane-utils session-migration sgml-base sgml-data
  switcheroo-control system-config-printer system-config-printer-common
  system-config-printer-udev ubuntu-docs ubuntu-mono ubuntu-session ubuntu-wallpapers
  ubuntu-wallpapers-focal unzip update-inetd upower usb-modeswitch usb-modeswitch-data
  usbmuxd va-driver-all vdpau-driver-all wamerican whoopsie-preferences x11-utils
  x11-xkb-utils x11-xserver-utils xclip xdg-dbus-proxy xdg-utils xfonts-base
  xfonts-encodings xfonts-utils xml-core xserver-common xserver-xephyr xserver-xorg
  xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-input-libinput
  xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-legacy xserver-xorg-video-all
  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-fbdev
  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-vesa xwayland
  yaru-theme-gnome-shell yelp yelp-xsl youtube-dl zenity zenity-common
0 upgraded, 537 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 172 MB of archives.
After this operation, 1241 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

Comment: Install it from source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through `pip`:

```
pip3 install --user mps-youtube
mpsyt
```

[mps-youtube on github](https://github.com/mps-youtube/mps-youtube)